# Remove column and remove blank space in report viewer

Tags: c#, ado.net, report-viewer2010

I need to remove some columns when generating a report. However, the columns are hidden, it leave a gap on the table.

My question is how can I remove this gap?

I using parameter to hide the whole columns when meet a string value

```
=Parameters!ReportParameterHideShow.Value.Equals("HideString")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I solved it after some searching. Just want to share to any who facing this problem.

"If you simply click on the Tablix Column to highlight both the header and data row and then change the Hidden property what you are doing is changing the individual Hidden properties of the header and data row simulatenously.  This means you have changed the text box hidden properities and NOT the actual Tablix Column.  This will result in the text boxes being hidden but the Tablix column will not hide thus the "whitespace".

HOWEVER, if you right click on the Tablix Column (that little gray bar ABOVE your header box, this will give you a pop up menu that has a Column Visibility option.  Use the Expression to indicate True or False for when you want it hidden.  You will notice that when you run the report and your condition is met that the columns to the right are now pulled over against the column to the left of your hidden column, thus eliminated the whitespace.  In addition, even objects outside the Tablix that are to the right of the Tablix will be pulled over as well.

You DO NOT need to set the Report property for ConsumeContainerWhitespace to True to make this work.  In fact, setting this property one way or another has no effect at all related to this issue."

thanks to NElliott01. From 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/9ee3f759-229d-45c2-9e41-5fa794e6aa2b